# Como, após uma requisição POST, receber o retorno JSON no C#?

Tags: php, c#, json, http-request

Preciso de que após fazer uma requisição **POST** **http**, eu receba também o **json** de retorno que está no *echo* do **php**.

Este é o código de teste em **php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['request']))
    {
        echo $jsonret = '{"request":"sim","name":"'.$_POST['request'].'"}';
    }
    else
    {
        echo $jsonret = '{"request":"não","name":"invalid"}';
    }
?>
```

Esta foi minha tentativa em **C#**, como [métodos assíncronos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx) devem ser sempre do tipo void, tentei usando uma [variável estática](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/98f28cdx.aspx), mas mesmo assim, ele não chega a alterar a **string**.

**Observação:** a requisição funciona sem nenhum problema.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RequestJson();
    MessageBox.Show(retornojson);
}
static string retornojson = "nulo";
public async void RequestJson()
{
    string req = "enviado";
    //url do arquivo
    string URL = "http://localhost/testjsonreturn";
    var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();

    //idusuario
    var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("request", req)
        });
    var request = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(URL, formContent);
    retornojson = request.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Porque dessa afirmação: `devem ser sempre do tipo void` e variável `static` é obrigado porque?

Comment: Porque a requisição só pode ser feita de maneira assíncrona, `var request = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(URL, formContent);`

Comment: Pera um pouco você fez uma afirmação que o método não pode ser `void` e isso não é verdade? inclusive o que você passou não é void é com retorno! Eu sei a solução para esse problema, mas, é com retorno? até sei com `Task` também!

Comment: Você quer a solução para esse código?

Comment: Sim, é possível por task fazer o retorno, se puder me dar a solução eu agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apesar da resposta do Virgilio está correta, gostaria de sugerir umas alterações.

Primeiro, a classe `HttpClient` implementa a interface `IDisposable`, então inicialize ela usando o bloco `using()`.

O `await HttpClient.PostAsync` retorna um `HttpResponseMessage`, este possui o `Status` da requisição, então é interessante que você valide o seu valor.

Por fim, a sua requisição retorna um objeto com um formato conhecido e esperado, então é interessante que você deserialize este objeto.

```
[DataContract]
public class RetornoModel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "request")]
    public string Request { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var model = Program.PostData("http://localhost/testjsonreturn", "enviado").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    public static async Task<RetornoModel> PostData(string url, string req)
    {
        var parametros = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        values.Add("request", req);
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parametros);

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return await Task.Factory.StartNew<RetornoModel>(() =>
                {
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetornoModel>(json);
                });
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 uma outra forma.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não é bem uma outra forma, apenas sugerir umas melhorias, afinal acredito que o AP não está familiarizado com o C#.

Comment: Sinceramente @TobyMosque eu fique na duvida quando ele restringiu somente para `void`, mas, sim tudo é válido!

Answer (score 2):

Tem 2 formas que conheço:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await RequestJson();
    MessageBox.Show(retornojson);
}

private static string retornojson;
public async Task RequestJson()
{
    string req = "enviado";            
    string URL = "http://localhost/testjsonreturn.php";
    var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();
    var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("request", req)
        });
    var request = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(URL, formContent);
    retornojson = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();            
    myHttpClient.Dispose();            
}
```

**ou**

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    retornojson = await RequestJson();
    MessageBox.Show(retornojson);
}

private static string retornojson;
public async Task<string> RequestJson()
{
    string req = "enviado";            
    string URL = "http://localhost/testjsonreturn.php";
    var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();
    var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("request", req)
        });
    var request = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(URL, formContent);
    return await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                        
}
```

Tinha alguns problemas o endereço por exemplo, faltou `.php` e quando o processo de requisição realmente era concretizado, faltou 1 linha de código:

```
retornojson = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

para ler o contéudo enviado pelo `PHP`.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente aqui, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Ok, @JoãoPedro ...